# What is the computational complexity of the following problem

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

Given any number $N$ find a positive integer $k$ such that: $N + 12 k$ is a square.

And the second case when we add an additional constraint that $k$ must be as small as possible.

Answer (score 1):

What’s the solution for N = 12m +  2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11?

You can prove that no solution exists or find a solution in O(log N). You can find the smallest solution in O(log N log log N) or more precisely in the time it takes to multiply numbers of log N digits.